# OpenVPN log not showing up in /var/log/messages file

Tags: logging, openvpn

When running **service openvpn status**, the output states

```
Status written to /var/log/messages
```

However, nothing shows up in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to running **service openvpn status** without proper permissions.  I had openvpn configured so that only root could alter the service, therefore when I checked the status as root, rather than a non-root user, it properly outputted the status to /var/log/messages.

Comment: Some additional information would be needed to make sense of this answer.

Comment: I elaborated a bit.  Can't really elaborate more than that......